# Scaling top side of a ring of cubes

Tags: transforms

I'm trying to shrink the rim of this rock base so the top is slightly smaller than the bottom.  But when I scale this selected rim, it pulls everything inward.  it looks good from the exterior wall but the interior is slanted inwards.

Is there a way to shrink the top of the ring of cubes such that their vertical center remains in place, and the edges come inward?

The base of the structure:
[image: Base of a hawaiian style house]

Exaggerated look at scaling the top:
[image: base of hawaiian structure scaled inwards]

I'd like to keep the vertical center of the cubes where they are, but have the interior and exterior faces slant inwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. You could inset the faces with <kbd>i</kbd> and then delete the edge loops:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of extruding the the top faces of the base structure in your first image, simply hit <kbd>I</kbd> to inset the faces and while using the *Inset* tool, hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to change the *Depth* (as it is called in the tool), which basically lets you move the inset faces up and down. While holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> you can change the height, when you release the key you can continue adjusting the inset width. When you've finished just left-click to confirm.

[image: inset and depth]